# Windows Phone won't wake up(unlock) after installing Windows 10 Preview

Tags: insider-preview, lock-screen

I have a problem with my Lumia 920. After installing Windows 10 technical preview (any version) via Windows Insider (slow or fast), and after I lock my phone using the lock button, I am unable to wake it up or unlock it using the double-tap option or the unlock button. The phone is not shut down, because I tried calling myself from another phone and it was ringing, but nothing is shown on the screen, it is simply dark. Only, when I do a soft reset I can start using my phone, but the next time I lock it, it happens again.

I don't have any lock screen application installed.

Is anyone able to help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is simply one of the risks you run by installing Windows 10 Mobile in its preview stage. Touch frequently stops working for me, apps just crash, etc., etc. The most I can suggest is a hard reset. And not installing Windows 10 Mobile on your main phone.